# Parsing of google apis

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, parsing

I'm new to ios and working on parsing and got the url shown below:-

```
@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",typedtext,kGOOGLE_API_KEY
```

But i am not able to parse it.

I am having no idea about this, how is should be done.

So please kindly help me out.

Comment: what does the link returns?

Comment: this link will return the place on map view.

Comment: What it return xml or json??

Comment: it will return the xml

Comment: This link is broken, provide the fill API

Comment: but i took it from https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search will it be wrong??

Comment: why don't you use a the api that give you back a Json? is easier to parse.  Ex. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

Comment: k i will work with this, but can u please provide me sample code using this api..

Comment: sure u can take ur time......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that link returns a json, you can put the response in a `NSData` and than with `JSONObjectWothData:options:error:` parse it.

**EX.**

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:urlPercoso]];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
});
```

Where json is a `NSDictionary`

then you receive a structure like that:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.42291810,
               "lng" : -122.08542120
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42426708029149,
                  "lng" : -122.0840722197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42156911970850,
                  "lng" : -122.0867701802915
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

so like data you can take al the info because now is just a dictionary, array, string and number value so then your can do that alone for more info look this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this its working code for xml parsing

https://github.com/71squared/TBXML